# Ejecutar script en python cada segundo

Tags: python

Amigos estoy desarrollando un script en python, a este lo pienso compilar a .exe. y para ello estoy utilizando cx_Freeze.

Ahora en mi .py quiero desarrollar una función que me ejecute el script automáticamente cada 5 seg y para ello estoy utilizando:

```
scheduler = Scheduler()
scheduler.add(5, 0, funcion)
while True:
    scheduler.run()
```

Pero el problema estaba que cuando lo compilaba, por que no podía ejecutar satisfactoriamente el .exe. Aparentemente lo he solucionado cambiando algunos paramentos del script desarrolle.
Estoy probando el script de varias formas, hasta ahora esta funcionado....voy a seguir con el testing, pero por el momento no voy a cerrar la pregunta.
Recibo todo tipo de sugerencias....

Comment: Quieres realizar un programa que ejecute una función cada segundo, o quieres ejecutar todo un script, una vez por segundo ? que sistema operativo estas usando, que versión de Python ? Saludos

Comment: @Elenasys y Santi92... recién veo que mi pregunta fue editada por otra persona. Básicamente es ejecutar una función cada 5 segundos y crear un proceso .exe en windows que se inicie cada vez que se reinicie el SO. Para ello estoy utilizando `scheduler = Scheduler()
scheduler.add(5, 0, funcion)
while True:
    scheduler.run()` Pero al crear el ejecutable me creaba un error que no me dejaba ejecutar el .exe satisfactoriamente. Le hice una modificación y voy a ver si cumple con el objetivo.

Comment: Dario, agrega toda esa información en tu pregunta, y especifica que error tienes al ejecutar el .exe! saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar [time.sleep()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm), definiendo que cada segundo se ejecute tu "script":

```
import time

def ejecutaScript():
    #Aquí agregas en contenido de tu script o ejecutas el script dentro de un archivo .py.
    python myscript.py
    print 'Ejecutando Script...'
    time.sleep(1)

while True:
    ejecutaScript()
```

Comment: Gracias por el script @Elenasys. Básicamente es ejecutar una función cada 5 segundos y crear un proceso .exe en windows que se inicie cada vez que se reinicie el SO. Para ello estoy utilizando                `scheduler = Scheduler() scheduler.add(5, 0, funcion) while True: scheduler.run() `                                                                                  Pero al crear el ejecutable me creaba un error que no me dejaba ejecutar el .exe satisfactoriamente. Le hice una modificación y voy a ver si cumple con el objetivo

Comment: Que bien Dario, trata de agregar el código que hayas tratado, además de los errores que encuentras para mayor documentación de tu pregunta =).