# Ejecutar Script con probabilidad de falla en Python cada segundo

Tags: python, script, crontab

Buenas tardes compañeros.

Soy relativamente nuevo en la programación y desarrolé mi primer Bot para unas tareas, el mismo ya se encuentra terminado pero tengo un pequeño problema para ejecutarlo constantemente ya que de vez en cuando falla por una razón ajena (a veces el servidor no envia la información y el programa cae, esto me sucededía cada 5-6hs cuando englobe el codigo en un While) pero es indispensable que cuando caiga se "reactive", por lo que encontré las siguientes soluciones:

1) Utilizar Contrab y modificarlo para que se ejecute cada 1 segundos
2) La siguiente solución: [Ejecutar script en python cada segundo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6786/ejecutar-script-en-python-cada-segundo)

Mi duda con la segunda solución, es si cae el programa, también cae este segundo? Si es así no sería lo que estaba buscando. Agradezco cualquier tipo de respuesta que me guia a que es lo mas indicado para esta solucion, de forma resumida ejecutar cada 1 segundo o menos un script que de vez en cuando falla.

Gracias

Comment: Mirate [Lanzar automáticamente un programa en python cuando se cierra por fallo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/148351/15089) es posible que sea lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/installing.html#installing-to-a-system-with-internet-access) es muy bueno cuando quieres que se ejecuten automaticamente tareas y si fallan, el mismo lo vuelta a ejecutar, tambien puedes configurar una notificacion via Email con [superlance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/superlance), en tu archivo `supervisord.conf` con esta configuracion

```
[eventlistener:crashmail]
command=/usr/local/bin/crashmail -a -m email1@example.com
events=PROCESS_STATE
```

Si quieres alguna configuracion extra, puedes usar esta referencia [Get notification from supervisord when a job exits](https://serverfault.com/a/244733)